# Installing armadillo on Mac, and setup with xcode

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to install armadillo on Mac, but have some problems running the example1.cpp. I have followed the readme.txt file.

1. I have xcode installed (and I can make simple c++ programs)
2. Installed cmake and run `cd my_build_folder`, `cmake ..` and then `make`.
3. Run `sudo make install`. (What this do?)

Then, when I try to compile the example code, I run `g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -larmadillo` (as the readme says), but i get this error:

```
example1.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'armadillo' file not found
#include <armadillo>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

But if I complile it like this (which is not recommended by the readme), I get no error: `g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -I /home/blah/armadillo-6.700.3/include -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -lblas -llapack`

I am not very good at this, so the problem is probobly simple.

Also a follow up question. If I want to code in xcode with armadillo, how should I setup the project? Do I have to link to armadillo in some way?

Thanks